# GetManifestResourceStream method, what are the parameters?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I have Assembly class.

What parameters should I pass to `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(?)`?

It says, that there should be string. But which one?

---

I have such code:

```
private string returnStringFile(string resName)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var strResources = assembly.GetName().Name + resName;
        var rStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strResources);

        var streamReader = new StreamReader(rStream);

        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

In line `var streamReader...` I have Exception:

> 'System.ArgumentNullException'

What should I pass to `GetManifestResourceStream` method?

I'm trying to read text file from my project, and return it as a string.

Comment: Google will direct you to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xc4235zt.aspx. "The case-sensitive name of the manifest resource being requested."

Comment: You can list available names using GetManifestResourceNames. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx